# Chrome media hub API

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, media-player

Last week Chrome released the media hub. This is a small button at the right of the browser's top bar, giving access to all the video and audio playing.

https://blog.google/products/chrome/manage-audio-and-video-in-chrome/

[image: The media hub]

Using the `<video>` element makes your player appears in this media hub, it just works.

But for youtube videos (see above), the media hub seems to be able to find a cover image, a color and a title / sub-title. However, I was not able to find any documentation about how to obtain this aspect with a standard video element. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're all in the same boat, after trying to dig the source in chromium with no luck, I was sending an email to the chromium developer for this question and got the useful link about [MediaSession](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session#set_metadata).

So following the docs, You can customize it by setting `metadata` property in the `mediaSession` to showing a title, description and artwork (a.k.a. background image) except the background color, That's because the background color is determined by pixels of the image automatically.

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {

  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: 'Never Gonna Give You Up',
    artist: 'Rick Astley',
    album: 'Whenever You Need Somebody',
    artwork: [
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    ]
  });
}
```

I have created the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gasol/427rtmnk/6) on the JSFiddle. the result shows as following.

[image: GMC]